# Google Maps constantly calling API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have this code to make it to update the markers, and yes it works fine but everytime it refresh, it calls Google Maps API, how can I make it call once, and update the markers only. I know there is guide out there and quite new to javascript, I tried but none works. Anyone can help with this?

```
var pokemon_name = "";
var pokemon_array = [];
var infoWindowContent = [];
var markers = [];
var pokeImage = [];
var markers_data = [];
var infos_data = [];
var icon_data = "";

jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API
    //callAPI();
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEYHERE&callback=callAPI";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});

function callAPI() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getpoke.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $("#refresh_form").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data) {

    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    // Display a map on the page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    map.setTilt(45);
    initialize(data);
            }
            });

}

setInterval(function(){callAPI();}, 10000);

 function deleteMarkers() {
        markers = [];
        infoWindowContent = [];
        pokeImage = []
}

function initialize(data) {

    deleteMarkers();

    var pokedata = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.ajax({
            url : "pokemonlist.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            var arr = lines[i].split('"');

            pokemon_id = arr[1];
            pokemon_img = arr[3];
            pokemon_name = arr[4];
            pokemon_id = pokemon_id.trim();
            pokemon_img = pokemon_img.trim();
            pokemon_name = pokemon_name.trim();

            pokemon_array.push([ pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name ]);
        }


    for (var i = 0; i < pokedata['data'].length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < pokemon_array.length; x++) {

    if (pokemon_array[x][0] == pokedata['data'][i]['pokemonId']) {
        pokemon_name = pokemon_array[x][2];
    }
    }

    pokemon_up = pokedata['data'][i]['upvotes'];
    pokemon_down = pokedata['data'][i]['downvotes'];
    pokemon_lat = pokedata['data'][i]['latitude'];
    pokemon_long = pokedata['data'][i]['longitude'];

    if (pokemon_down >= pokemon_up) {

    }
    else {
    //markers_data.push([pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name ]);
    markers.push([pokemon_name, pokemon_lat, pokemon_long ]);
    }
    }

    // Info Window Content

    var nowTime = Date.now();

    for (var i = 0; i < pokedata['data'].length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < pokemon_array.length; x++) {
    if (pokemon_array[x][0] == pokedata['data'][i]['pokemonId']) {
        pokemon_name = pokemon_array[x][2];
    }
    }

    pokemon_up = pokedata['data'][i]['upvotes'];
    pokemon_down = pokedata['data'][i]['downvotes'];
    pokemon_created = 1e3 * pokedata['data'][i]['created'],
    p = pokemon_created + 900000 - nowTime;

    hour_data = parseInt(p / 6e4 % 60),
    sec_data = parseInt(p / 1e3 % 60);

    if (hour_data.toString().length == 1) {
            hour_data = "0" + hour_data;
    }

    if (sec_data.toString().length == 1) {
            sec_data = "0" + sec_data;
    }

    pokemon_trainer_name = pokedata['data'][i]['trainerName'];

    pokemon_time_expire = hour_data + ":" + sec_data;

    text_write = "<h3>"+pokemon_name+"</h3><br>Source:"+pokemon_trainer_name+" <br><br>Time expire: <span id='expire_"+i+"'>"+pokemon_time_expire+"</span>";

    if (pokemon_down >= pokemon_up) {

    }
    else {
    infoWindowContent.push([text_write]);
    text_write = "";
    }
    }

     var pokeImage = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < pokedata['data'].length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < pokemon_array.length; x++) {
    if (pokemon_array[x][0] == pokedata['data'][i]['pokemonId']) {
        pokemon_img = pokemon_array[x][1];
    }
    }

    pokemon_up = pokedata['data'][i]['upvotes'];
    pokemon_down = pokedata['data'][i]['downvotes'];

    if (pokemon_down >= pokemon_up) {

    }
    else {
    pokeImage.push([pokemon_img]);
    }
    }

    // Display multiple markers on a map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

    // Loop through our array of markers & place each one on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(position);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
            icon: pokeImage[i][0]
        });

        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

    // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
    var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
        this.setZoom(16);
        google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
    });

     }
     });

}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is pretty chaotic.  I'm not sure if it solves everything, but I can see where the main problem is.

First: var bounds must be inside function initialize.

For the rest, try this; just replace callAPI() by my function.  I guess if your code didn't cause errors, this should fix your question.

```
var firstTimeLoaded = false;
// load the markers (from server)
function callAPI() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getpoke.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $("#refresh_form").serialize(),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data) {
      // Display a map on the page.  Obviously this needs to be done only once.
      if(firstTimeLoaded == false) {
        firstTimeLoaded = true;
        mapOptions = {
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
        map.setTilt(45);
      }
      initialize(data);
    }
  });
}
// this means the function callAPI() will be called, every 10 seconds.
setInterval(function(){callAPI();}, 10000);
```

...

```
function initialize(data) {
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks and sorry for the messy code! All actually went wrong is because of the variable bounds?

Comment: Well, your code stops at bounds.extend(position);  Javascript doesn't have var bounds in its scope (variable is not declared within the same function); so javascript just stops executing the rest of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Take callAPI() out of the setInterval so it calls only once. Then, call initialize() in the setInterval instead.

Comment: I agree.  I chose to solve it a little differently, for practical purposes, mainly in order to change as little as needed